# Jquery click toggle, if/else cases both triggered

Tags: jquery

I've just made a really simple toggle button. Function checks the state (a class), and executes resizing animation/re-sets state.

But when clicked, somehow both cases are triggered (target div appears and disappears). How can this happen with just one click?

```
$('.box').live('click',function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass('.op'))
      {
         $(this).siblings('.lh').animate({ width: '0', marginLeft: '80'}, 300);
         $(this).removeClass('.op');
      } else
      {
         $(this).siblings('.lh').animate({ width: '80', marginLeft: '0'}, 300);
         $(this).addClass('.op');
      }
});
```

Comment: hmmm, you should be caching some of these things... I'll do a quick re-write for you. Is this the only click event going on for .box?

Comment: Is it possible that you're using some AJAX on the page that reloads the part of the page containing the script that attaches the handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use dot notation when referring to classes for the class manipulation functions.

It should be `.addClass('op')`, `.removeClass('op')` and `.hasClass('op')` - that should fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

`box.hasClass('.op')` try without dot. like `box.hasClass('op')` but I guess this is not the real problem

```
$('.box').live('click',function(){

          if ($(this).hasClass('op'))
          {
             $(this).siblings('.lh').animate({ width: '0', marginLeft: '80'}, 300);
             $(this).removeClass('op');
          } else {
             $(this).siblings('.lh').animate({ width: '80', marginLeft: '0'}, 300);
             $(this).addClass('op');
          }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use `live`.  Instead, try `click`:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
          if ($(this).hasClass('.op'))
          {
             $(this).siblings('.lh').animate({ width: '0', marginLeft: '80'}, 300);
             $(this).removeClass('.op');
          } else
          {
             $(this).siblings('.lh').animate({ width: '80', marginLeft: '0'}, 300);
             $(this).addClass('.op');
          }
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I agree, he shouldn't be actively listening for the event using live() or on(). There doesn't seem to be any DOM removal/attaching going on.